# Are there any server settings to fix addslashes behaviour on calls to file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents, addslashes

Up until about a week ago, wordpress websites on our host showed no issues.

However, since this morning we noticed an issue whereby admin pages failed to load in wordpress.  On other sites on the same server one page of one site was being displayed with all single and double quotes preceded with a backslash like this, \" and \'.  We checked and found more sites using file_get_contents are suffering from the same issue.

We asked our host, who said it was a mod_security issue, but turning it off for the relevant pages has no effect.  Adding stripslashes() directly to the output of the most critical pages and functions on non-wordpress sites got those rendering acceptably again.

However, rather than hacking around in wordpress, is there any setting that we should be asking the host to set (or that we can set since we have ssh access to the server) that can address this issue?

Does anyone know what kind of setting might cause this function to add slashes to content?

I tried disabling slashes via php.ini but it doesn't change the behaviour on those sites.

Any thoughts for where to start are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever told you it was mod_security is wrong.  It's a PHP setting, magic_quotes_gpc, which controlls whether slashes are added to input.  It's been deprecated for some years now, and should always be off.  If it's on then you might be able to override it and turn it off again with a .htaccess file, but if that's not an option you'll have to ask your host to check the magic_quotes_gpc setting.

Comment: Hi, we have magic_quotes_gpc off and I also set it manually to off in php.ini just in case, although trying to set it in htaccess didn't work.  I then tried setting it with php but it still allowed \" to come through from file_get_contents().  We've had it switched off for 2 years, no idea how this error can possibly occur at the moment.

Comment: PHP may be loading a different .ini file than the one you think it is, or it's failing to load your .ini file and just falling back to default settings instead.  PHP can also load multiple .ini files, some of which can override the base php.ini file.  You need to check what ini files PHP is actually loading and what its settings are at the time it starts to actually run a script.  You can do that easily enough by creating a script that only contains phpinfo().  You'll be able to check what ini files are loading and the state of magic_quotes_gpc

Comment: We've checked our settings and it shows the magic quotes as off, now, after having the host update it.  However, although post/get etc are not now suffering from that issue, file_get_contents() still does.  Until now, I wasn't aware that function had that issue in the first place. Are there any other settings that affect this function's behaviour with respect to slashes and quotes?